# Can someone explain what "video acceleration" is?

Tags: video, graphics, hardware-acceleration

Basically, a user came to me complaining that when she opened a certain video file in VLC, she received an error saying:

```
"Your video output acceleration driver does not support the required
resolution: 1470x525 pixels. The maximum supported resolution is
1470x526.

Video output acceleration will be disabled. However, rendering videos
with overly large resolution may cause severe performance degradation."
```

First of all, the error doesn't really make sense.  The acceleration driver doesn't support 1470x525, but then states that the max supported is actually one pixel higher than that.

Second, if I go into Tools --> Preferences --> Video and uncheck the box for "Accelerated video output (overlay)", the video plays just fine without error.

The system in question does not have a dedicated GPU, just onboard graphics, specifically:

```
user@box123[~]$ lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
```

I'm not really sure what to do particularly because I don't understand what "video acceleration" is in this case.  I generally understand the term "hardware acceleration" I think --- i.e. if a dedicated GPU were available,  using hardware acceleration would use the GPU to boost performance (right?).  But in this case all we've got is onboard Intel graphics.  Typical Google searches for things like "Video acceleration" don't really yield a good explanation about what is going on, what pieces of hardware are doing what, etc.

Comment: "I settled on ServerFault because it potentially has to do with hardware. I hope this is okay." https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ubw5N8iVDHI

Comment: Hardware acceleration means the video decoding is offloaded to the GPU, in this case it fails for some reason and falls back to software (CPU-powered) decoding, which works just fine because the CPU is powerful enough to do so (but uses valuable resources, it may be slowing the machine down).

Comment: "managing the hardware or software of servers, workstations" is listed under what is appropriate.  This is a question about the hardware (GPU/CPU) and software (VLC) of a workstation, that includes a query about "Video acceleration" to determine what the best course of action is in dealing with an error message that has to do with the hardware and software of a workstation.  Should probably amend that help page to say something else if this isn't the right place.

Comment: Don't worry about choosing the wrong site. As a new user it can be hard. However if your question is well formulated and interesting the worst thing that can happen is that it gets moved.

Comment: Maybe the intergrated gpu supports hardware acceleration? I have no clue about the error message vlc is throwing though.